# Creating instance of implementation in interface in static method?

Tags: java, reflection, constructor, interface, static-methods

recently i tried to create something like this: Create interface with static method that would return instance of class implementing that interface. Implementing class would have private constructor and interface will create instance of that class via reflection. Sample code here:

```
static Implementation getImplementation(){
    Constructor<Implementation> constructor = Implementation.class.getDeclaredConstructor();
    constructor.setAccessible(true);
    return constructor.newInstance();
}
```

I ommited exception handling. 
Is this code valid by any chance for some purpose, or is it just horrible anti-pattern?

Comment: It does seem to unnecessarily tie the interface to the implementation. Why not just put `createInstance` in the `Implementation` class?

Comment: Well, i had in mind that this will enforce someone else to use interface and not create instance of implementation like Impl impl = new Impl(); because constructor in implementing class is private (well, as long as he would not se reflection too).

Answer (score 0):

This is often done with an abstract `ImplementationFactory` which provides a static method like

```
public static ImplementationFactory newInstance() { ... }
```

`ImplementationFactory` then has a method like `Implementation newInstance()`.

See [`TransformerFactory.newInstance`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/TransformerFactory.html#newInstance()) for example.

There are different ways to implements this. Like reading the name of the implementing class from some resource under `META-INF/services`.